# What is the most efficient way to read N entities from an Azure Table structure

Tags: asynchronous, azure, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Background - will be using .NET 4.0, Azure SDK 1.7, Azure Table Storage

Problem
How to most efficiently (= fastest processing time ) to read N entries, where N is a large # (1000's to millions) of entities, and each entity is very small (<200 bytes) from a set of Azure tables, where upfront I know the PartitionID and RowID for each of the entities ie [(P1,R1),(P2,R2),...,(PN,RN)].

What is the most efficient way to 'batch' process such a request. Naturally, underneath there will be the need to async / parallelise the fetches, without causing threadlocks either through IO locks or Synchonisation locks, ideally I should see the CPU reach >80% throughput for the server making the calls to Azure Table storage, as this processing should be CPU bound vs IO or Memory bound.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are asking for "fastest" processing time to read from Azure Storage, here are some general tips that made my performance improve (top ones are the most important):

1. Ensure the Azure Storage has been created since July 2012.  This is the Gen2 of Azure Storage and it includes storage on SSD drives.
2. In your case, table storage has increased scalability targets for partitions for Gen2 of Azure Storage: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/11/02/windows-azure-s-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets.aspx

   - 10 Gbps network vs 1 Gpbs networks
   - Single partition can process 20,000 entities/second
3. .NET default connections change this number (I think this might be addressed in the new SDK, but not sure): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/d84ba34b-b0e0-4961-a167-bbe7618beb83
4. You can "warm" Azure Storage, the more transactions it sees the more of the controller/drive cache it will use.  This might be expensive to constantly hit your storage in this way
5. You can use MULTIPLE Azure Storage accounts.  This can distribute your load very efficiently (sharding): http://tk.azurewebsites.net/2012/08/26/hacking-azure-for-more-disk-performance/
6. You have several ways to architect/design in Table Storage.  You have the partition key and the row key.  However, you also have the table itself..remember this is NoSQL, so you can have 100 tables with the same structure serving different data.  That can be a performance boost in itself and also you can store these tables in different Azure Storage accounts. RowKey-> PartitionKey -> Table -> Multiple Storage Accounts can all be thought of as "indexes" for faster access
7. I dunno your data, but since you will be searching on PartitionKey (I assume), maybe instead of storing 1,000,0000 really small records for each PartitionKey have that in zip file and fetch it real quick/unzip and then parallel-query it with linq when it is in the local server.  Playing with caching always will help since you do have a lot of small objects.  You could probably put entire partitions in memory.  Another option might be to store a partition key with column data that is binary/comma seperated etc.
8. You say you are on the Azure 1.7 SDK...I had problem with it and using the StorageClient 2.0 library.  I used the 1.8 SDK with the StorageClient 2.0 library.  Something of note (not necessarily performance), since they may have improved efficiency of the libraries over the last 2+ years

Comment: Thank for your response Bart. Our design uses a lot of small pieces of information as we are representing a complex mesh of information and we only determine runtime which pieces of it to fetch. We are getting mixed results depending on whether we use, Parallel or Async code, we see a lot of either IO or Synchronisation locking, challenged to get the CPU to burst past 10% utilisation

Comment: Have you thought about persisting your small pieces/segments in some kind of delimited format in a single column per partition or row-key?  Retrieving larger files is going to be more efficient.  Your operations are going to be I/O bound, there is a difference between "async operations", which pass work onto secondary threads and keep the main system functional (i.e. ASP.NET web apps or Windows forms) and doing "parallel concurrency": highly computational work like doing a huge math problem.  The latter can scale to use up to 100% of the CPUs, the former can't since threads are I/O bound.

Comment: Having said that above, there are patterns that you can use that can make parallel concurrency more efficient with data.  Especially the pipeline patterns, where they work like a car assembly and do small tasks but as soon as they are done they pass them off to the next step (or thread) and then keep doing that.  Then u don't have to wait for all your data to return...

Comment: appreciate your feedback. We will take a look at persisting (in a non normalized fashion) clusters or the information in time, for now we are trying to get the raw processing performance as good as possible. We are basically doing computation, but we are challenged to find a way to wipe out either Synchronisation overhead, if we do async, or IO overhead if we do Parallel code. I have heard of someone getting performance of 30,000 items (30 partitions, 30 threads) in 1.4 sec ... our performance is way below that and we are unable to figure out the cause.

Comment: Yup scaling out to multiple partitions or tables across different Azure Storage accounts with the new Gen2 Azure Storage should get you there. Azure Storage is not the fastest NOSQL-like solution..I had pretty good results with Redis on a Linux VM, but that is more of a in-memory cache/database hybrid.  If you are looking for raw performance a distributed cache might be your best option with a fallback to Azure Table Storage.